# The stalk of the image sheaf on a normalization curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

My question is based on exercise II.6.9 in  Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

Suppose that $X$ is a projective curve over $k$ (an algebraically closed field). Let $\tilde{X}$ be its normalization and $\pi: \tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be the projection map. For each point $P\in X$, let $\mathscr{O}_P$ be its local ring and $\tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}$ be the integral closure of $\mathscr{O}_P$. Then my question is:

> Is there a relationship between the stalk of $\pi_*\mathscr{O}_\tilde{X}$ at $P$ and the local ring $\tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}$? Are they equal? If it's true, how to prove it?

**My attempt.**

In the affine case, suppose $X=\operatorname{Spec}A$ for some domain $A$. I know that $\pi$ is just the ring extension $A\hookrightarrow\tilde{A}$, where $\tilde{A}$ is the integral closure of $A$ in its field of fractions. And $P$ corresponds to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$. Then $\tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}$ is the integral closure of $A_\mathfrak{p}$. The stalk of $\pi_*\mathscr{O}_\tilde{X}$ at $P$ can be finally expressed as a direct limit of local rings $\{\tilde{A}_f\}$, where $f$ is taken over all elements in $A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$. So the question is translated into a problem of commutative algebra. That is, is it true for  $\tilde{A_\mathfrak{p}}=\varinjlim\tilde{A}_f$?

Maybe we need something given by the assumption on $X$, i.e. $A$ is noetherian and of dimension $1$. But I still have no strategy to deal with it. Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Diego that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Comment: One always has equality $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}=\tilde{\mathcal{O}}$, since $\tilde{X}=\underline{\operatorname{Spec}}_X\tilde{\mathcal{O}}$ by definition, see tags [035E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035E), [0BAK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BAK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are. The formation of integral closure commutes with localization. See Proposition 5.12 in Atiyah-MacDonald's Commutative Algebra book.

Answer (score -2):

I think your attempt is right. $\tilde{A_\mathfrak{p}}=\varinjlim\tilde{A}_f$ is true because you are working in an integral domain(curve implies integral), so everything is included in the function field, and taking colimit is the same as taking the union.